# Wrap with spaceBetween and center

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put 2 buttons on the same line, with the maximum horizontal space between them (one button will be at the most left and the other at the most right). But when there's no horizontal space for both, I want them to be displayed centered vertically, one above the other.

When there is enough space:

[image]

When there is not enough space:

[image]

I've tried the Wrap widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) in several different ways, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Per the info in this link [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14006), alignment is based on the longest line. A (hacky) solution I came up with is to add an invisible line that takes the full width of your parent widget. This will force a wrap and bring the alignment setting into play.

```dart
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    const SizedBox(width: double.infinity), // full width line
    Widget1,
    Widget2,
  ],
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to achieve this, hope this helps:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Wrap(
        spacing: 16, // add spacing between buttons
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Button 1'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Button 2'),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need the buttons aligned with the left and right of the screen. With an arbitrary spacing value (such as 16) this will not be achieved.